# Facebook on Android tablets has tiny dialogs

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

On Galaxy Nexus 7 device, I have got our app to run and can successfully login and use Facebook features, but the dialogs are all far too small when in landscape orientation.

Here is the Login screen on the Scrumptious example app:

[image]

and here is the Request dialog in our own app:

[image]

As you can see in these images, especially the second one, there is no way the dialog should be so tiny. This only happens on Android tablets - it doesn't happen on Android phone or iOS devices.

Does anyone know what the issue might be? I have the following lines in my Manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"   android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true"/>
```

and

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

I found these on other questions where there were problems with dialog sizes, but neither of these have fixed the issue.

I'd appreciate some advice or pointers on what the cause of this might be.

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? This should be fixed in 3.6.

Comment: I'm using 3.5.2. However, I submitted a bug report to Facebook and they said that landscape is currently unsupported, they didn't say anything about upgrading to 3.6. I'll try upgrading and report back.

Comment: To follow up, upgrading the SDK did indeed solve these issues. For some reason, the person handling the bug report I submitted on Facebooks bug report system didn't mention upgrading, just a blanket "Facebook doesn't support landscape mode as yet" which is annoying.

Comment: Can you link to the bug report? We do support landscape mode.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/613003702082152/